# Package witharrows

Tags: equations, errors, packages, installing, witharrows

I want to deal with the environment to insert explanations, like this:
[image: Description]

produced, on Overleaf, with the following commands:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[portuguese]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{fouriernc}
\usepackage{witharrows}
\usepackage{cancel}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{tikz}


\renewcommand{\CancelColor}{\color{red}}

\begin{document}

$$
\begin{WithArrows}
\lim_{x \to +\infty} \left[ x \left( \sqrt{x^2-1} -x\right) \right] & =  +\infty \left( \color{red}+\infty - \infty \right) \Arrow{Multiplicar e dividir pelo conjugado}\\
& =  \lim_{x \to +\infty}  \frac{\left( \sqrt{x^2-1} + x\right) \color{red} \left( \sqrt{x^2-1} -x\right)}{ \color{red} \left( \sqrt{x^2-1} -x\right) }\\
&= \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x \left( \left( \sqrt{x^2-1} \right)^2 - x^2 \right)}{\sqrt{x^2-1} -x}\\
& = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{x \left( \left( x^2-1 \right) - x^2 \right)}{\sqrt{x^2-1} -x} \\
& = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2-1} -x}\\
& = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2 \left( 1-\frac{1}{x^2} \right)} + x}\\
& = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{-x}{\sqrt{x^2}\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+x}\\
& = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{-x}{x \left( \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+1 \right)}\\
& = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{-\cancel{x}}{\cancel{x}\left( \sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+1\right)}\\
& = \lim_{x \to +\infty} \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1-\frac{1}{x^2}}+1} \\
& = \frac{-1}{\sqrt{1}+1}\\
& =  -\frac{1}{2}
\end{WithArrows}
$$

\end{document}
```

Hoewver, when I use these command on Texmaker on my computer, an error message is given:

```
! Package witharrows Error: Your version of LaTeX (especially expl3) is too
(witharrows)                old. You can go on but you will probably have
(witharrows)                other errors if you use the functionalities of
(witharrows)                witharrows.

Type <return> to continue.
 ...                                              
                                                  
l.38 ...rror:nn { witharrows } { expl3~too~old } }
                                                  

LaTeX does not know anything more about this error, sorry.

Try typing <return> to proceed.
If that doesn't work, type X <return> to quit.
```

How can I fix this, or find and install manually this package?

Comment: Can you show the `.log`, please?

Comment: Above this is the log fraction. All content is too long.

Comment: Use https://pastebin.com/ or some other tool like that.  The part of the `.log` you show is the error message that tells you to update `expl3`, so that's what you should do, but with the `.log` I might be able to give you more direct help

Comment: I think is a tex machine problem?? what are you using Miktex, Texlive???? version??? or  How long has it been since you have done an update? this code runs fine in my machine with texlive2020

Comment: Here my error: 

https://pastebin.com/up9LC7zQ 

I am with MiKTeX 2.9. I never made an update. Updating solves? Or need to re-install another version?

Comment: yes, update to the latest version, and the editor, the best is TeXlive.

Answer (score 1):

(I'm the author of `witharrows`.)

Reading your log file, I see.

> Package: expl3 2020-01-12 L3 programming layer (loader)

This version of `expl3` is too old to run the most recent versions of `witharrows`.

You should update thoroughly your TeX installation and it will work.